# How can I remotely access my Linux GUI?

Tags: remote-desktop, scientific-linux

I have a Linux machine at work (scientific Linux 6) and I would like to be able to remotely log-in from home. Security-wise we are already allowed, just the current setup requires SSH + Putty and I only get the terminal.

What can I do/install so I can access the GUI from home?

Comment: If your home system is linux too, you can do `ssh -X hostename` and start gui there.

Comment: VNC is another option

Comment: My home machine is Windows 7 and remote is Linux

Answer (score 10):

If your remote client is running Windows, you can enable X11 forwarding in PuTTY and install an X server for Windows such as 
[Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/). This allows your Linux GUI applications to integrate with the Windows desktop, appearing as normal, locally-rendered windows.

If your remote client is Linux, you can just use `ssh -X`.

Comment: Hi, my home machine is Windows and work machine is Linux?

Comment: *This is the easiest solution*. There is no need for any additional setup on the Linux machine.

Comment: Seems like Xming is not free. There's a free version available from 2007.

Comment: `ssh -X`, really it's just a flag? Linux is terrific

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use [Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/linux.aspx), it is adaptable for any kind of OS even for smart phones. You install it on the devices you want and can create a profile and be able to connect to your linux from any device. If you find it difficult to set up, I can help you.